# Focus+Context via Brushing not display when select area

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i've a problem with Focus+Context via Brushing (bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367#index.html)
That work well when i load it, but when I select the zone to display in main chart, I've nothing in the main chart

Before select area :
http://puu.sh/hdB8a/f112d63d12.png

After select area :
http://puu.sh/hdBa0/c744f6e914.png

the code : (variable data is an array containing object with value and date attribute)

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: this.h-70, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = this.w - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = this.h - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = this.h - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(6).tickSize(2),
    xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom").ticks(6).tickSize(2),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickSize(2);

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brushed);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(new Date(d.date)); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

var area2 = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x2(new Date(d.date)); })
    .y0(height2)
    .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.value); });

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("fill","none")
    .attr("stroke","#000")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("fill","none")
    .attr("stroke","#000")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime();
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return new Date(d.date); })));
y.domain([d3.min(data.map(function(d) { return d.value; })), d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.value; }))]);
x2.domain(x.domain());
y2.domain(y.domain());

focus.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area)
    .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)")
    .attr("stroke",chartcolor);

focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .attr("stroke","none")
    .attr("fill",chartcolor)
    .call(xAxis);

focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("stroke","none")
    .attr("fill",chartcolor)
    .call(yAxis);

context.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area2)
    .attr("stroke",chartcolor)
    .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)");

context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("stroke","none")
    .attr("fill",chartcolor)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
    .call(xAxis2);

context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x brush")
    .attr("stroke","none")
    .attr("fill",chartcolor)
    .attr("fill-opacity","0.125")
    .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .attr("y", -6)
    .attr("height", height2 + 7);



function brushed() {
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent() );
    focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
    focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT :

I resolve my problem, instead of d3.svg.area(), I use d3.svg.line()

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(new Date(d.date))+margin.left+margin.right; })
    .y(function(d) { return y(Number(d.value))+margin.top+margin.bottom; });

var line2 = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x2(new Date(d.date))+margin2.left+margin2.right; })
    .y(function(d) { return y2(Number(d.value))+margin2.top+margin2.bottom; });
```

And line(data) instead of datum(data)

```
    focus.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)")
    .attr("stroke",chartcolor);


context.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line2(data))
    .attr("stroke",chartcolor)
    .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)");
```

Thank you for looking

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: nothing in my log and javascript console

Comment: Could you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: this is not possible, data was fill with a database and this code run for redraw a NodeRED node

Comment: Well the best we can do then is point you to a working example, which you've already found yourself.

Comment: i posted in case I do a visible mistake in my code,because I'm a beginner with D3